# Bootstrap Select2 doesn't firing select event on paste until type any word

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use bootstrap select2 v4.* on my site (Yii 2.x) and have met a problem: 
The event `select2:select` doesn't firing on text paste with ctrl+v until I type any text. After typing - it works fine. What i'm doing wrong? 
JS:

```
function formatResult(data) {
    var content = '<span>' + data.id + '\t' + data.text + '</span>';
    return $(content);
};

function formatSelection(data) {
    var content = '<span>' + data.id + '</span>';
    return $(content);
}

$('#wiz-asin-search').select2({        
    tags: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeholder: 'specify asin..',
    ajax: {
        url: '/keyword-tracker/get-mwslisting-asins',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                searchAsin: params.term
            }
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return { results: data.results };
        }
    },
    templateResult: formatResult,
    templateSelection: formatSelection,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
}).on('select2:select', function(){
    var asin = $(this).val();
    console.log('asinSearch.change fired: ' + asin);

    validationHighLight(false);
    validateAsin(asin);
});
```

Comment: The main suggestion is: problem with `change` event. By some reason it is not firing with first paste. When open the page, and paste the same string `asdf` few times - nothing happens. If I take another string `test_string` and paste it second time - it works fine.
I've tryed to trigger this event manually after init, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is: 
initialize `select2` with some data.

```
$('#wiz-asin-search').select2({
    // allowClear: true,
    tags: true,
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    data: [
        {
            id: ' ',
            text: 'testAsin'
        }  
    ],
...
```

and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

***You simply use this code:***

```
$('#yourElement').select2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and resolved it using the [createTag](https://select2.org/tagging#customizing-tag-creation) callback.

```
$('select').select2({
  createTag: function (params) {
    var term = $.trim(params.term);

    if (term === '') {
      return null;
    }

    if (this.$element.find('option').length === 0) {
      this.$element.append($('<option data-select2-tag="true">'));
    }

    return {
      id: term,
      text: term
    }
  }
});
```